# Find text from another column and replace them with adjacent values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

For example:

```
Column A    Column B           Column F  Column G
   50          61                 50         1.9
   63          69                 61          0
   72          74                 63         1.8
                                  69         1.96
                                  72         2.1
                                  74         2.5
```

Column G has the values of column F.

I want to find a text in columns A and B by using text in column F and replace it by using text in column G like this result:

```
Column A    Column B           Column F  Column G
   1.9         0                  50         1.9
   1.8         1.96               61         0
   2.1         2.5                63         1.8
                                  69         1.96
                                  72         2.1
                                  74         2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your cells are numbers (as shown in the example), convert them from 'text' to 'number' format. Then:

Type on C1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$F$1:$G$6,2,0)
```

Type on D1:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$F$1:$G$6,2,0)
```

Drag formulas to the other rows belonging to the same columns.

<sub>[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892028/understanding-the-vlookup-formula-in-excel/20892869#20892869) I explain how the `vlookup` formula works.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using a formula and some helper columns, you can use `VLOOKUP`.

To do this, insert a column after column A (this will become 'B' after that). In cell B2, put the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, G:H, 2, 0)
```

[Note: columns F:G moved to G:H after insertion of column after column A]

And fill to the end of column A. Once done, copy and paste the values of column B onto column A, after which you delete column B.

Repeat for column B.